# java swing checkboxes java swing

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I have a question with my java application. 
I create a dice role game on java swing, created separate object for every dice that shows different dice numbers on my frame every time clicking throw button getting problem with jcheckboxes everytime. 
I want when checkbox is checked the dice would stay with that number and dont change.

I trying this this way:

```
if(ch1.isSelected() == true){  
    ch1.setSelected(true);
    Die[0].setValue(0);     
}
```

ch1 is my checkbox I want to keep always checked ,and keep value 0 but when button throw pressed, it still giving a random number for that dice.

maybe you know how to keep checkbox always checked ?

Comment: You can do ch1.setEnabled(false) to make it non-toggleable.. but doesn't this defeat the purpose of a checkbox?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
private void ch1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    Die[0].setValue(0);
}
```

Comment: i have everything in a method that are inside action listener class, it don't work that way

Comment: I also just tested it myself, and it appears to [be working](http://puu.sh/lOj22/ea825dc839.png)

Comment: please briefly tell me what it does, i dont want to a same values just to make a new class

Comment: What do you mean... You don't need a new class, just rewrite your actionListener... Maybe provide more code for us to help you?

Comment: i posted some in answer

Comment: You should return that array instead of putting it inside of the actionListener

Comment: like that ? DieClass.Die[0].getValue();

Answer (score 0):

this method inside action listener where i have my objects and cant access them from where

public void myDices() {

```
    Die[] Die = new Die[10];
    Die[0] = new Die();
    Die[1] = new Die();
    Die[2] = new Die();
    Die[3] = new Die();
    Die[4] = new Die();
    Die[5] = new Die();
    Die[6] = new Die();
    Die[7] = new Die();
    Die[8] = new Die();
    Die[9] = new Die();

    diceClass.roll(Die);
    diceClass.display(Die);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dice object:

```
public class Dice {

private boolean canRoll;
private int value;

public Dice() {
    canRoll = false;
    value = 0;
}

public int roll()
{
    if(canRoll) {
        // Roll the dice!
        value = /* Roll algorithem */;
    }
    return value;
}

public void setCanRoll(boolean k)
{
this.canRoll = k;
}

}
```

Than create a array of dice objects. You can set the canRoll boolean with the setCanRoll(boolean k) method. Roll the dice and print the output to the screen.

If this is not what you mean than maybe: ch1.setEditable(false);